# Retrieve all the group records if at least one row matches the condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have following table created from series of SQL queries and now I need to retrieve records if at least one row in the group matches a condition.
 [image]

For example I wan't to retrieve all group records where at least one of device's state is **FAILED**. In the example I provided here, except for MERCHANT_ID c0030-10155511 (where both devices are in success state), I wan't to retrieve other records where at least one device is failed along with it's success device. For example, both records of MERCHANT_ID c0040-10196477 , need to fetch since only one device is failed.

how can we achieve this in MySQL.

Comment: Please edit your question in order to include sample data in textual format and not as an image.

Comment: the table goes, out of view, hence I included an image

Comment: It is preferrable to truncate some of the column, or even omit a whole column if it is irrelevant to the question. The difficult thing with an image is that we can't use it as a source to a mock up of the sample data provided.

Comment: images of data are virtually useless, why not just provide the data as text so there is the possibility of using it

Comment: @CoolCK I have given an answer by creating a sample structure from the info you provided (discarding unwanted columns),Check to see if it is what you really want.Please provide with minimal data set in textual format for us to provide a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    yourTable
WHERE
    merchant_id IN
    (
        SELECT
            merchant_id
        FROM
            yourTable
        WHERE
            state LIKE '%FAILED')
```

Comment: This doesn't fetch success rows correspond to success.

Comment: Try the new statement, I think this is what youre looking for

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: It's a pity though. This isn't a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, your table name is device_table

```
SELECT * 
FROM device_table d1 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM device_table d2 
  WHERE d2.state like '%FAILED' 
        AND d1.merchant_id = d2.merchant_id
)
```

If the state column is type enum, the query can be written as

```
SELECT * 
FROM device_table d1 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM device_table d2 
  WHERE d2.state in ('DOWNLOAD_FAILED', 'INITIATE_FAILED', etc...) 
        AND d1.merchant_id = d2.merchant_id
)
```

Or,

```
SELECT * 
FROM device_table d1 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM device_table d2 
  WHERE d2.state not in ('INITIATE_SUCCESS') 
        AND d1.merchant_id = d2.merchant_id
)
```